# How to setup web service cluster using MAAS and JUJU

Tags: server, juju, maas, ceph

I have 5 physical servers.  The first server has been designated for MAAS and has MAAS 2.0.0 installed and running.  The other 4 servers have been commisioned and ready in MAAS.

What I would like to do is use one of the servers as a load balancer, and then the other 3 for the service nodes using JUJU.  Each one of the service nodes has 8 cores, 32gb ram, and a little over 1tb from multiple 15,000rpm drives.

The services nodes needs to run Apache, and Mysql (percona) and be apart of Ceph.

What I don't understand though... When I use JUJU and add Ceph, how do I ensure the other lxc containers (apache, mysql) are installed onto the Ceph filesystem, and not the root disk?

Comment: I am not sure it there is support in maas and juju for this. You can try editing the preseed files to mount the ceph filesystem to any point you want. You can try out the steps [here](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.4/configure.html#altering-the-preseed-file) and [here](http://caribou.kamikamamak.com/2015/06/26/custom-partitioning-with-maas-and-curtin-2/).

Comment: Thanks for the response, @BilalBaqar.  That makes my decision a bit easier.  I will simply use JUJU to deploy Ceph then simply add the services to those nodes manually.